# What does iwa/iwl/iwm/iwn mean in FreeBSD?

Tags: wifi, freebsd, intel

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440 which I was looking to install FreeBSD on.  The laptop has an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 chip which doesn’t seem to be supported (yet).

On my travels, researching whether I might need to install an available driver or some such thing, I've come across some terms which I presume are acronyms:

- iwa
- iwl
- iwm
- iwn

My presumption is that *iw* stands for something like Intel Wireless?  **Is that correct and what is the letter at the end?**

I thought perhaps it had something to do with wireless standards, like 802.11a/b/c/n/ac/etc. but that doesn’t seem to be the case.

Neither does it seem to be the case that *iwa* is older than *iwn* as I’ve found someone working on the 7260 **[under a git repo titled iwa](https://github.com/erikarn/freebsd-iwa/tree/master/src/sys/contrib/dev/iwa)** and have found a **[man page for iwn which doesn’t mention the 7260, but does mention older models](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/4/iwn/)** (I think).

Comment: Could you use the word in a sentence? :)
Some example would be nice were these terms are used.
But I think they are all driver names and that *iwa* is a new driver that is currently developed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are different driver names for different devices. The [iwn man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iwn&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and the [iwi man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iwi&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) document these drivers. The `iwa` driver you found just might work, but be aware that getting it built isn't trivial and will take some work.

Comment: Oh, I think the i is for intel and w is for wireless, after that I think it's somewhat arbitrary.